# I just want to use callback method "setMouseCallback" in openCV to pass a array of pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

This is only key part of the codes and I am wondering how to pass the array of pointer via callback method:

```
void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int, void *param)
{   
 Mat *mats = (Mat *)param;
 cout << "address of param: " << (Mat *)param << endl;
 cout << "address of mats: " << mats << endl;
 cout << "address of the first value of mats: " << *mats<< endl;
 ...
}
int main(int argc,const char* argv[])
{
 Mat *mats[2] = {&img,&img2};
 cout << "address of mats : "<< mats << endl;
 cout << "address of the first value of mats: " << *mats << endl;
 cout << "address of the first value of mats: " << mats[0] << endl;
 cout << "address of the second value of mats: " << mats[1] << endl;
 cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
 setMouseCallback("Cropping app", mouse_callback,mats);
}
```

the result will be crashed and how can I do it correctly?

```
address of mats : 0x7fffd326f9b0
address of the first value of mats: 0x7fffd326f9d0
address of the first value of mats: 0x7fffd326f9d0
address of the second value of mats: 0x7fffd326fa30
--------------------------
address of param: 0x7fffd326f9b0
address of mats: 0x7fffd326f9b0
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims <= 2) in writeMat, file /usr/local    
/lib/opencv-    2.4.8/modules/core/src/out.cpp, line 117
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /usr/local/lib/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/out.cpp:117: error: (-215)    
 m.dims <= 2 in function writeMat
 address of the first value of mats: [Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a `Mat**` to the callback function, so the cast is wrong. Try this:

```
void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int, void *param)
{
  Mat **mats = param;
  cout << "address of mats : "<< mats << endl;
  cout << "address of the first value of mats: " << mats[0] << endl;
  cout << "address of the second value of mats: " << mats[1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really helpful. I lost in this yesterday.